# Can we implement 'Screen Shot' feature in jitsi meet using ReactNative

Tags: react-native, jitsi

Can we implement 'Screen Shot' feature in jitsi meet using ReactNative. If Yes, May i know how we can achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can find several threads regarding screenshot capture in jitsi like [jibri hack](https://community.jitsi.org/t/take-screenshot-of-conference/65171/2) and [already defined function](https://community.jitsi.org/t/screenshot-video-call/21650).
And you will get more response if you ask in the community for your use case. Thanks